# ViewFlipper change image dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, viewflipper

I have a task to show 5 images periodically. I'm using ViewFlipper for this. The images are loaded dynamically from gallery or camera.

I got stuck with modifying the image source at runtime i.e user should be able to change the current image he is viewing.

I can get the  current index, now I want to change the image source from gallery at run time

// code to initialise the flipper

```
vf_profile_slide = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.profile_slide_vf);
    int gallery_grid_Images[]={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2};

    for(int i=0;i<gallery_grid_Images.length;i++)
    {           
        setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);            
    }
    /*  tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
        addNewImageToFlipper(mContext, tempBmp);
     */
vf_profile_slide.setAutoStart(true);
vf_profile_slide.setFlipInterval(5000);
vf_profile_slide.startFlipping();
```

//On button click i m feteching the image index

```
PROFILE_INDEX = vf_profile_slide.getDisplayedChild();
```

//calling this function...

```
private void addImageToFlipperAt(Context mContext,int index,Bitmap bm)
{           
    ImageView iv_new = (ImageView)             findViewById(vf_profile_slide.getChildAt(index).getId());
    iv_new.setImageBitmap(bm);      
    vf_profile_slide.addView(iv_new,index);     
}
```

the new image is added successfully.... but i want the current image at that index gone... that is not happening .... tell me where i m going wrong

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Maybe if you could elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve, and a little bit more about what you tried so far?

Comment: Bex, sorry for the goofup... i have elaborated more.... hope i'm clear this time :)

Comment: Cool. Better, but it would be even easier if you would give us a bit more code.

Comment: bex, here's d code :)

Comment: Maybe you can remove the removeViewAt-method as well, to remove the view you don't want anymore?